# How to fetch the level wise value using Jmeter Json Extractor

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have pasted a json file below, want to get the inner most levelID value(ie **ff808181620ce25501620d08e4dc0061**) and the parent of it(**ff808181620ce25501620d08e4b9005e**). Tried $.levelID[3];$.levelID[4] correspondingly for variable names: levelID & parentlevelID but failed the get the values mentioned in the brackets above.

`{
    "levelID":null,
    "levelType":0,
    "levelName":null,
    "learningObjective":null,
    "reusablelevelID":"",
    "reusableClid":"",
    "duration":null,
    "subLevels":[{"levelID":"ff808181620ce25501620d08e492005b","levelType":1,"levelName":"ch1","learningObjective":null,"reusablelevelID":"0","reusableClid":"0","duration":null,
        "subLevels":[{"levelID":"ff808181620ce25501620d08e4b9005e","levelType":2,"levelName":"sch1","learningObjective":null,"reusablelevelID":"0","reusableClid":"0","duration":null,
            "subLevels":[{"levelID":"ff808181620ce25501620d08e4dc0061","levelType":3,"levelName":"u1","learningObjective":null,"reusablelevelID":"0","reusableClid":"0","duration":null,
                "subLevels":null,"wbList":[],"cList":null,"classroomResources":[],"qList":[]}],"wbList":[],"cList":null,"classroomResources":[],"qList":[]}],"wbList":[],"cList":null,"classroomResources":[],"qList":[]}],
    "wbList":[],
    "cList":[],
    "classroomResources":[],
    "qList":[]
}`

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your levelID is in level 2 of the JSON (inside `[{`) while each `.` represent 1 level.

You need two [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as Post processor of your request, both with same JSON path expression:

```
$..levelID
```

For `ff808181620ce25501620d08e4dc0061` choose Match No. 4 and the other Match No. 3

It will return two different variable with your both requested values.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath

   def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
   def levelTypes = JsonPath.read(response, '$..levelType').sort()
   vars.put('innerMost', JsonPath.read(response, '$..[?(@.levelType == ' + levelTypes.get(levelTypes.size()-1) + ')].levelID').get(0).toString())
   vars.put('parentOf', JsonPath.read(response, '$..[?(@.levelType == ' + levelTypes.get(levelTypes.size()-2) + ')].levelID').get(0).toString())
   ```
3. Once done you will be able to refer the most inner levelID as `${innterMost}` and its parent as `${parentOf}` where required.

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Jayway JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)